# Parsing AutoSys JIL with perl

Tags: perl, autosys, jil

I have an assignment to parse out AutoSys JIL files.  This is a JIL job definition, it is a config file that the AUTOSYS scheduler reads in and runs. , Imagine a file formatted like this, with thousands of job definitions like the one below, stacked on top of each other in the exact same format. All beginning with the header and ending with the timezone.

```
/* ----------------- COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY ----------------- */

insert_job: COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY   job_type: CMD
command: /bin/bash -ls
machine: capser.com
owner: twins
permission: foo,foo
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: "04:00"
description: "Forever, and ever and ever"
std_in_file: "/home/room217"
std_out_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.out"
std_err_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.err
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/autosys_profile"
timezone: US/Eastern
```

This is the script. I need to extract the job, machine and command from the job definition above.  It works fine, but eventually I am going to want to store the information in some kind of container and send it, while this script writes out the results line by line in the terminal. Right now I am redirecting the results to a temporary file.

```perl
#!/foo/bar/perl5/core/5.10/exec/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Basename ;

my($job, $machine, $command)  ;
my $filename = '/tmp/autosys.jil_output.padc';
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename)
  or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";
my $count = 0;
while (my $line = <$fh>) {
    #chomp $line;
    if($line =~ /\/\* -{17} \w+ -{17} \*\//) {
    $count = 1; }
    elsif($line =~  /(alarm_if_fail:)/) {
    $count = 0 ; }
    elsif ($count) {
             if ($line =~ m/insert_job: (\w+).*job_type: CMD/) {
             $job = $1   ;
             }
             elsif($line =~ m/command:(.*)/) {
             $command = $1  ;
             }
             elsif($line =~ m/machine:(.*)/) {
             $machine = $1  ;

             print "$job\t $machine\t $command \n ";      
             }
        }


    #sleep 1 ;
   }
```

My question is When I place the print  *$job, $machine $command*  statement within the last elsif statement, it works fine. However when I place it out side of the last elsif statement, like the example below the output is duplicated over and over again - each line is duplicated like four to five times in the output. I do not understand that. How come I have to put the print statement within the last elsif statement to get the script to print out one line at a time, correctly.

```perl
elsif ( $line =~ m/machine:(.*)/ ) {
    $machine = $1;
}

print "$job\t $machine\t $command \n ";
```

---

#### Reformat of above code for readability

```perl
#!/foo/bar/perl5/core/5.10/exec/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Basename;

my ( $job, $machine, $command );
my $filename = '/tmp/autosys.jil_output.padc';

open( my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $filename )
        or die "Could not open file '$filename' $!";

my $count = 0;

while ( my $line = <$fh> ) {

    #chomp $line;
    if ( $line =~ /\/\* -{17} \w+ -{17} \*\// ) {
        $count = 1;
    }
    elsif ( $line =~ /(alarm_if_fail:)/ ) {
        $count = 0;
    }
    elsif ( $count ) {

        if ( $line =~ m/insert_job: (\w+).*job_type: CMD/ ) {
            $job = $1;
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ m/command:(.*)/ ) {
            $command = $1;
        }
        elsif ( $line =~ m/machine:(.*)/ ) {
            $machine = $1;
            print "$job\t $machine\t $command \n ";
        }
    }

    # sleep 1;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you check if `$job`, `$command`, and `$machine` are populated before printing them out.  You can reset them to `undef` where you set `$count = 1`

Comment: Also, proper indentation goes along way to understanding how your code executes.  Also, if you are going to have these `if-elsif`.... ladders, it is good practice to have an `else` clause to catch a situation you may not have anticipated.

Comment: You can use `perltidy` to reformat your code for you, according to whatever coding guidelines you like.

Comment: Your Perl code is disgraceful. Please remember that anyone likely to answer your question will be familiar with something more standard, such as that described in [`perlstyle`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlstyle.html). Making your code readable has a huge benefit to you and your colleagues, and it is rude to post a jumble of characters like that, expecting us to wade through it. I have added a normalised version of your program to your question in the hope that someone may read that far.

Comment: I get that the first code block is an example of what a print statement would look like *"outside the `elsif` brackets"*, but what is the block that begins `COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY`?

Comment: @xxfelixxx: *"You can use perltidy ... according to whatever coding guidelines you like"* I really wish you could!

Comment: If the `COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY` block is an example of your input data, then running *your own code* against that data produces `COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY   capser.com   /bin/bash -ls ` which is what I would expect. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Borodin, you just need to setup your `.perltidyrc` correctly....yes it doesn't handle everything, but it is pretty good.

Comment: @xxfelixxx: My biggest frustration is that *anything* in parentheses is either space-surrounded or not. So `my($x)` is treated the same as `for(0..99)`. It's far from comprehensive.

Comment: That sounds like you are a regular expression and a patch contribution away from what you want...go for it :)

Comment: @xxfelixxx: If you can write some code for me that I can test and push then I'll consider it. Reading and understanding [the code from `Perl::Tidy`](https://st.aticpan.org/source/SHANCOCK/Perl-Tidy-20170521/lib/Perl/Tidy.pm) is beyond my means at present.

Comment: @Borodin, Possibly, I have some bandwidth right now, could you open a RT bug ticket with some examples of what you are looking for, to be used as test cases.

Comment: @xxfelixxx: That's not how it works. If you fork the existing code and send me a pull request then I may take a look.

Comment: @xxfelixxx: Perl tidy  -- THANKS GUYS !!!!  I use html tidy and bash shellchecker - was looking for a perl compatible service. you guys rule

Comment: @Borodin, awesome contribution. I will take your advice. SOrry so sloppy.

Comment: @capser: But you should never need to use `perltidy` on your own code. There's no reason not to enter it correctly in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've said in my comment, *please format your code sensibly*. Without doing so you will get people either ignoring your question, or being grumpy about answering like me

- Let's assume that the unidentified text block is just a sample of your input
- Let's also assume that, even though your code works fine with your sample data, there are some data blocks in the real data that don't work
- On top of that, I'm assuming that any data field value that contains spaces requires enclosing quotes, which makes your example `command: /bin/bash -ls` incorrect, and invalid syntax

Please also make sure that you have given a proper example of your problem with runnable code and data. If I execute the code that you show against your sample data then everything works fine, so what problem do you have?

As far as I can tell, you want to display the `insert_job`, `machine`, and `command` fields from every JIL data block whose `job_type` field is `CMD`. Is that right?

Here's my best guess: [**xxfelixxx's** comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841287/parsing-autosys-jil#comment80632872_46841287) is correct, and you are simply printing all the fields that you have collected every time you read a line from the data file

My solution is to transform each data block into a hash.

It is dangerous to use comments to delineate the blocks, and you have given no information about the ordering of the fields, so I have to assume that the `insert_job` field comes first. That makes sense if the file is to be used as a list of imperatives, but the additional `job_type` field on the same line is weird. Is that a genuine sample of your data, or another problem with your example?

Here's a working solution to my imagination of your problem.

```
#!/foo/bar/perl5/core/5.10/exec/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $data = do {
    local $/;
    <DATA>;
};

my @data = grep /:/, split /^(?=insert_job)/m, $data;

for ( @data ) {

    my %data = /(\w+) \s* : \s* (?| " ( [^""]+ ) " | (\S+) )/gx;

    next unless $data{job_type} eq 'CMD';

    print "@data{qw/ insert_job machine command /}\n";
}


__DATA__
/* ----------------- COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY ----------------- */

insert_job: COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY   job_type: CMD
command: /bin/bash -ls
machine: capser.com
owner: twins
permission: foo,foo
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: "04:00"
description: "Forever, and ever and ever"
std_in_file: "/home/room217"
std_out_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.out"
std_err_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.err
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/autosys_profile"
timezone: US/Eastern

/* ----------------- COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_AGAIN_DANNY ----------------- */

insert_job: COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_AGAIN_DANNY   job_type: CMD
command: /bin/bash -ls
machine: capser.com
owner: twins
permission: foo,foo
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: "04:00"
description: "Forever, and ever and ever"
std_in_file: "/home/room217"
std_out_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.out"
std_err_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.err
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/autosys_profile"
timezone: US/Eastern

/* ----------------- NEVER_PLAY_WITH_US_AGAIN_DANNY ----------------- */

insert_job: NEVER_PLAY_WITH_US_AGAIN_DANNY   job_type: CMD
command: /bin/bash -rm *
machine: capser.com
owner: twins
permission: foo,foo
date_conditions: 1
days_of_week: mo,tu,we,th,fr
start_times: "04:00"
description: "Forever, and ever and ever"
std_in_file: "/home/room217"
std_out_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.out"
std_err_file: "${CASPERSYSLOG}/room217.err
alarm_if_fail: 1
profile: "/autosys_profile"
timezone: US/Eastern
```

#### output

```
COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_DANNY capser.com /bin/bash
COME_AND_PLAY_WITH_US_AGAIN_DANNY capser.com /bin/bash
NEVER_PLAY_WITH_US_AGAIN_DANNY capser.com /bin/bash
```

Comment: The jil is a job definition, or a config file for a job scheduler - like cron. The scheduler is Called Autosys, it is made by computer associates, and many people hate it. This post should benefit someone who wants to parse the jil files. Jil stands for Job Information Language

Comment: really appreciate your attention - <em>If I execute the code that you show against your sample data then everything works fine, so what problem do you have?</em>  When I place the print statement outside of the last elsif block, it prints the right answer, but prints it four times. If I place the print statement inside the block, I get the correct output to the screen - once and only once - but I don't see why. From what I understand, the print statement should work outside the last elsif block - but it does not. It prints duplicates.

Comment: @capser: Outside your `if`/`elsif` chain you are printing the data you have accumulated *every time* you read a line. You don't want that; you want to print only when you have all the data from a block.

Answer (score 0):

This is a ksh solution to turn a JIL file into comma separated file you can open in excel

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

# unix scprit to flatten autorep -q

resetVar()
{
    AIF=""
    AD=""
    AH=""
    BF=""
    BN=""
    BS=""
    BT=""
    COM=""
    COD=""
    DC=""
    DOW=""
    DES=""
    EC=""
    IJ=""
    JL=""
    JT=""
    MAC=""
    MES=""
    MRA=""
    NR=""
    OWN=""
    PER=""
    PRI=""
    PRO=""
    RC=""
    RW=""
    SM=""
    ST=""
    SEF=""
    SOF=""
    TRT=""
    WF=""
    WFMS=""
    WI=""
    LSD=""
    LST=""
    LED=""
    LET=""
    STA=""
    RUN=""
}


writePartToFile()
{
 echo "$AIF;$AD;$AH;$BF;$BN;$BS;$BT;$COM;$COD;$DC;$DOW;$DES;$EC;$IJ;$JL;$JT;$MAC;$MES;$MRA;$NR;$OWN;$PER;$PRI;$PRO;$RC;$RW;$SM;$ST;$SEF;$SOF;$TRT;$WF;$WFMS;$WI" >> $TO_TPM
 #echo "$AIF;$AD;$AH;$BF;$BN;$BS;$BT;$COM;$COD;$DC;$DOW;$DES;$EC;$IJ;$JL;$JT;$MAC;$MES;$MRA;$NR;$OWN;$PER;$PRI;$PRO;$RC;$RW;$SM;$ST;$SEF;$SOF;$TRT;$WF;$WFMS;$WI" 
 resetVar

}

JOB_NAME="flatten JIL"
part1=""
part2=""


#---------------------------------
if test "$1." = "."
then
   echo "Missing first parameter (jil file to flatten)"; 
   exit 1;
fi

if test "$2." = "."
then
   echo "Missing second parameter (resulting flat file)";
 exit 1;
fi

TO_FLATTEN=$1
TO_RESULT=$2
CLE_FILE="lesCles"
CLE_TMP="lesClesTmp"
TO_TPM="tempFichier"
TO_STATUS="statusFichier"

rm $TO_RESULT
rm $CLE_TMP
rm $CLE_FILE
rm $TO_TPM
rm $TO_STATUS

echo 'alarm_if_fail;auto_delete;auto_hold;box_failure;box_name;box_success;box_terminator;command;condition;date_conditions;days_of_week;description;exclude_calendar;insert_job;job_load;job_terminator;machine;max_exit_success;max_run_alarm;n_retrys;owner;permission;priority;profile;run_calendar;run_window;start_mins;start_times;std_err_file;std_out_file;term_run_time;watch_file;watch_file_min_size;watch_interval;last_start_date;last_start_time;last_end_date;last_end_time;status;run' >> $TO_RESULT;
 while read line; do    
    if test "${line#*:}" != "$line"
    then        
      cle="$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f 1)"
      #echo "cle = $cle"
      part2="$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f 2)"   
      #echo "part2 = $part2"        
      val="$(echo "$part2" | cut -d" " -f 2)"
      #echo "val = $val"    
    fi  
    if test "$cle" = "insert_job"
    then
    #on n'est sur la premiere ligne
        if test "$IJ." = "."
        then
            ;                           
        else          
            if test "$BN." = "."
            then             
             echo $IJ >> $CLE_TMP
            else
             echo $BN >> $CLE_TMP
            fi      
            writePartToFile         
        fi
        IJ=$val
        JT="$(echo "$line" | cut -d":" -f 3)"                   
    else    
    #on n est pas sur le premiere ligne 
        val=$part2
        case $cle in
            alarm_if_fail) AIF=$val;;
            auto_delete) AD=$val;;
            auto_hold) AH=$val;;
            box_failure) BF=$val;;
            box_name) BN=$val;;
            box_success) BS=$val;;
            box_terminator) BT=$val;;
            command) COM=$val;;
            condition) COD=$val;;
            date_conditions) DC=$val;;
            days_of_week) DOW=$val;;
            description) DES=$val;;
            exclude_calendar) EC=$val;;
            insert_job) IJ=$val;;
            job_load) JL=$val;;
            job_terminator) JT=$val;;
            machine) MAC=$val;;
            max_exit_success) MES=$val;;
            max_run_alarm) MRA==$val;;
            n_retrys) NR=$val;;
            '#owner') OWN=$val;;
            permission) PER=$val;;
            priority) PRI=$val;;
            profile) PRO=$val;;
            run_calendar) RC=$val;;
            run_window) RW=$val;;
            start_mins) SM=$val;;
            start_times) ST=$val;;
            std_err_file) SEF=$val;;
            std_out_file) SOF=$val;;
            term_run_time) TRT=$val;;
            watch_file) WF=$val;;
            watch_file_min_size) WFMS=$val;;
            watch_interval) WI=$val;; 
        esac        
    fi

done  < $TO_FLATTEN;
#Traiter derniere occurence
if test "$BN." = "."
then
    echo $IJ >> $CLE_TMP
else
    echo $BN >> $CLE_TMP
fi      
writePartToFile     

echo "Les cles"
cat $CLE_TMP | sort | uniq > $CLE_FILE
cat $CLE_FILE
rm $CLE_TMP

#------------------------------
 while read line; do        
    autorep -J ${line} -w  >> $TO_STATUS;   
done  < $CLE_FILE;
#----------------------------------------
echo " Resultats"
while read line; do
unJob="$(echo "$line" | cut -d";" -f 14)"
details="$(grep -w  "$unJob" "$TO_STATUS" | head -n 1)" 
LSD="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $2}')"
if test "$LSD" = "-----"
then
    LST=""
    LED="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $3}')"
    if test "$LED" = "-----"
    then
        LET=""
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $4}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
    else
        LET="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $4}')"
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $6}')"
    fi
else
    LST="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $3}')"
    LED="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $4}')"
    if test "$LED" = "-----"
    then
        LET=""
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $6}')"
    else
        LET="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $5}')"
        STA="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $6}')"
        RUN="$(echo "$details" | awk '{print $7}')"
    fi
fi

echo " ligne= ${line};${LSD};${LST};${LED};${LET};${STA};${RUN}"
echo "${line};${LSD};${LST};${LED};${LET};${STA};${RUN}" >> $TO_RESULT
resetVar
done  < $TO_TPM;
```